# Photos layer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, gps, photos

I have some photos. They have GPS information. I want to add them with a layer like markers to OpenLayers map. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There's an example adding photos from an GeoRSS feed.

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/georss-flickr.html

I think this is as elegant solution as any other.  Just take the example GeoRSS feed and alter it to contain your own photo details, including the link to the photo.

Comment: Thanks but i want to use photos GPS in details. Like as [link](http://regex.info/exif.cgi)

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Well you'd need to find something to parse the photos, extract the coordinates, and export that out in the GeoRSS format.  You might be able to do this all in the client side with Javascript (https://github.com/jseidelin/exif-js), but I think you may find it easier to process the photos using Python (https://gist.github.com/erans/983821) for the job.  It all depends on what skills/resources you have available.